# SSIS data transformation from excel

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I am importing excel file tables into SQL Server using SSIS.
While importing i need to change the data of particular column. When and how it can be achieved?

Eg: My Excel contains a column "Country" with values like "India", "United States", "Russia". However When transfering the data to SQL server, I want it to be stored as "IND", "USA", "RU"

Comment: Use a Lookup, and point it to the table that contains the translation values. 

This is pretty basic SSIS stuff. Did you try Googling?

Comment: I am new to this stuff. Neways Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a CountryCode, CountryName lookup (either a table or another excel) from http://www.iso.org/iso/country_names_and_code_elements

2) Create connection for that table/file along with your main excel

3) Use a lookup component with source as the new table/file and 'lookup' the Code using the Name in the SSIS dataflow.

4) Use the new Code column while inserting into table.